# IllegalArgumentException from Fragmentmanager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a repeating crash from google play :

```
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1293)
  at     android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
      at     android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2900)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2207)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1326)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2900)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2207)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1326)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

now google play doesn't show any problems with my code but i'm guessing it's still something from my code ...

Anyone ever came across a situation like this ?

How can I fix it if I don't know where it is ?

**Edit :**

I found out it happens only on Galaxy phones any trouble with them ?

Tnx for the helpers.

Comment: could you add some context and code here, please?

Comment: it's a hugh app , i don't know what to post ... the stack trace doesn't point to any specific class , that's my problem

Comment: yeah you're right... I removed my downvote. Can this be something related with layouts? Is the app running on a different device?

Comment: the app is now on production so it has more devices than on testing , the layouts seem to be ok works on phones and tablets

Comment: Hi did you find what caused this crash? I have similar report from Play Store

Comment: well i had a list fragments within a fragment which i  was the problem , I removed thelist and put a recyclerview instead , worked like a charm.